# Building a regex, how to remove redundant line breaks?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string like this

```
"a           a            a  a aaa b c d e f a g a aaa  aa           a       a"
```

I want to turn it into either

```
"a b c d e f a g a"
```

or

```
"a                        b c d e f a g a                   "
```

(whichever's easier, it doesn't matter since it'll be HTML)

`"a"`s are line breaks ( `\r\n` ), in case that changes anything.

Comment: Whoops, updated the question. `C#`, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Went with this:

```
private string GetDescriptionFor(HtmlDocument document)
{
    string description = CrawlUsingMetadata(XPath.ResourceDescription, document);
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"(\r\n(?:[ ])*|\n(?:[ ])*){3,}", RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);//(?:[^\S\r\n|\n]*\1)+

    string result = regex.Replace(description, "\n\n");
    string decoded = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(result);
    return decoded;
}
```

It does, as it's supposed to, ignore all line breaks except cases where it matches three or more continuous line breaks, ignoring whitespace, and replaces those matches with `\n\n`.

Answer (score 1):

*Generally your code should be:*

```
s.replace(new RegExp("(\\S)(?:\\s*\\1)+","g"), "$1");
```

Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/5hghq/) fiddle.

*But, depends on what those characters **a**, **b**, **c**, ... represent in your case/question, you might need to change `\\S` to other class, such as `[^ ]`, and then `\\s` to `[ ]`, if you want to include **\r** and **\n** to being collapsed as well >>*

```
s.replace(new RegExp("([^ ])(?:[ ]*\\1)+","g"), "$1");
```

Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/WPfPG/) fiddle.

*However if **a** is going to represent string **\r\n**, then you would need a little more complicated pattern >>*

```
s.replace(new RegExp("(\\r\\n|\\S)(?:[^\\S\\r\\n]*\\1)+","g"), "$1");
```

Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ddNWz/) fiddle.

Comment: I have posted my answer when the OP's question has no **C#** tag, just **html** and **regex**, so I came with **javascript** solution. Regex pattern is same for C#, so you should be able to clone it easily...

Comment: To OP: C# regex is more powerful than JS regex. You can unescape the string escape sequences and put in a literal string in C#.

Comment: I won't for now, since I don't know C# itself, except for the regex. I'll include the regex here for OP to test, if it works, then you can modify your answer. @"(\r\n|\S)(?:[^\r\n\S]*\1)+". the replace string is the same @"$1". Check for replace all function in C#.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly, the goal is to remove duplicate copies of a specific character/string, possibly separated by spaces.  You can do that by replacing the regular expression `(a\s*)+` with `a` ; `+` for multiple consecutive copies, `a\s*` for `a`s followed by spaces  How precisely you do that depends on the language: in Perl it's `$str =~ s/(a\s*)+/a /g`, in Ruby it's `str.gsub(/(a\s*)+/, "a ")`, and so on.

The fact that `a` is actually `\r\n` *shouldn't* complicate things, but might mean that the replacement would work better as `s/(\r\n[ \t]*)+/\r\n/g` (since `\s` overlaps with `\r` and `\n`).

Answer (score 0):

If you need C# code and you want to collapse **JUST** \r\n strings with leading and trailing whitespaces, then the solution is pretty simple:

```
string result = Regex.Replace(input, @"\s*\r\n\s*", "\r\n");
```

Check this code [here](http://ideone.com/gBkrM).

Comment: I also want to remove adjacent `\r\n`s and replace them with just one `\r\n`

Comment: @Nice - And that is **exactly** what the code above is doing, correct? You should know that `\r` and `\n` are also white-space characters...

Answer (score -1):

Try this one:

```
Regex.Replace(inputString, @"(\r\n\s+)", " ");
```

Comment: Ria, your code will remove each `\r\n` and that is not what OP has asked for!